# Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end error when iterating over shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Folder sharing does not work on Google Shared Drive, so I am trying to automate sharing through Google Apps Script.

I tried to write code with reference to several examples, but I kept getting errors and asked questions.

I got an error saying:

> 'Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end', and I confirmed that sharing of some files was not set.

Below is the code I wrote. How can I fix this problem?

```
function myFunction() {
  var folderid = ""
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    Logger.log(files.next().getName());
    files.next().setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue:

`.next()`  returns the `next` file in the `folder`. If `folder` has 1  file, `files.hasNext()` returns true and `files.next()` returns `file1`. Calling `files.next()` again returns

> Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end'

- First call to iterator:file#1

  > Logger.log(files.next().getName());
- Second call to iterator: next file(not available)

  > files.next().setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

If folder had 5 files, `Logger` would've logged names of files 1,3 and 5.  Sharing would've been set on files 2 and 4.

#### Solution:

Call `files.next()` only once after checking with `files.hasNext()`

#### Snippet:

```
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const nextFile = files.next();//one call
    Logger.log(nextFile.getName());
    nextFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  }
```

#### References:

- [Iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol)
- [File iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)