# file.next().setTrashed(true) not working in function to delete file from google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to move a file in my google drive folder to the trash after I process it. In this function, I process it then I want to trash it but there is an error on the trashing line: `Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. (line 20)`

```
// Import CSV file data into spreadsheet
function importCSV () {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xyz");
  const file = folder.getFilesByName("name.csv");
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    const csvString = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();
    const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString);
    const lastRow = csvSheet.getLastRow();
    csvSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    file.next().setTrashed(true);// Delete the csv file so next time there aren't name conflicts
  } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `file` is FileIterator.
- In your if statement, `file.next()` is used 2 times. In this case, 1st `file.next()` is different from 2nd `file.next()`. If the file of the filename `name.csv` are existing only one file, when 2nd `file.next()` is run, an error occurs. I thought that This might be the reason of your issue.
- When you want to move the processed file to the trash box, it is required to use `setTrashed` for the 1st `file.next()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function importCSV () {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xyz");
  const file = folder.getFilesByName("name.csv");
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    const f = file.next(); // Added
    const csvString = f.getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Modified
    const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString);
    const lastRow = csvSheet.getLastRow();
    csvSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    f.setTrashed(true); // Modified
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

Comment: Understood, that makes perfect sense. Yes, there was only this one csv file in the folder so it was throwing an error, but when I removed .next() it wouldn't even process it. It makes sense to assign file.next() to a variable so you can refer back to that specific file when you want to go and delete it