# How to search a Specific File Name and File Type together in Google Drive folder from multiple sub folders using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

In Google Drive, I'm searching for a **specific file** that contain words **"Verification Visit"** and **"completed"** where the **file type** need to be a **spreadsheet(.xlsx)** type file. The searching will go through a parent folder and then  into sub folders. So the particular files will be stored in some of the sub folders (*Google Drive -> Parent folder -> Sub folders*).

Here is the code:

```
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, sheet, voidFolder, excluded) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
  var folder = childFolders.next();
  var failIter = folder.searchFiles('title contains "completed"');
  while (failIter.hasNext()) {
    var fail = failIter.next();
    var failWithTitle = fail.getName();
    var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
    var output = [];
    var path;
    var Url;
    var fileID;
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      var fileName = childFile.getName();
      path = parentName + ' |--> ' + fileName;
      fileID = childFile.getId();
      Url = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + fileID;
      output.push([fileID, fileName, path, Url]);
    }
    if (output.length) {
      var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
      sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, output.length, 4).setValues(output);
    }
    getChildFolders(
      parentName + ' |--> ' + fileName,
      folder,
      sheet,
      voidFolder,
      excluded
    );
  }
}
```

I have successfully implemented the two conditions (file that contains **specific name** and also the **file type**) in this function. The problem here is the searching process of the file in the sub folder only does on the first sub folder and it doesn't proceed searching into the next sub folder. It only list the files from the first sub folder but not from the other sub folders.

I am getting an error message telling **"Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end."**

Comment: Do you understand the error? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237540/cannot-retrieve-the-next-object-iterator-has-reached-the-end-error-when-iterati/61237719#61237719)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issues:

- You are not checking whether [parent.getFolders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfolders) returns any folder, so when you reach the end of the hiearchy and there are no further subfolders on that level, [childFolders.next();](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator#next) fails with the error you are getting.
- You are not iterating through the [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator) (for example, with `while (folderIter.hasNext()) {`), so you are only getting the first folder in the iterator.
- You are iterating through the files that contain `completed`, but inside each file iteration you are iterating again with `folder.getFilesByType` to check the MIME type (check the available [search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms#file_properties)). That is to say, you are iterating through the files in that folder twice, which will most likely return duplicate results.

#### Suggested workflow:

- For each folder, look for your desired files with [Folder.searchFiles](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchfilesparams) with the two conditions you want (title contains `completed` and mime type corresponds to MS Excel) and iterate through the results with `FileIterator.hasNext()` in a `while` loop.
- For each folder, look for the corresponding subfolders via `Folder.getFolders()`, and loop through the results with `FolderIterator.hasNext()` and a `while` loop. For each of these subfolders, call your function recursively.
- Use [SpreadsheetApp.flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) to make sure the sheet gets updated every time `setValues` is used, so that previous data is not overwritten.

#### Code sample:

```
function getChildFiles(folderName, folder, sheet) {
  var fileIter = folder.searchFiles("title contains 'completed' and mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'");
  var folderId = folder.getId();
  var output = [];
  while (fileIter.hasNext()) { // Iterate through files in folder
    var file = fileIter.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var path = folderName + ' |--> ' + fileName;
    var fileID = file.getId();
    var Url = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + fileID;
    output.push([fileID, fileName, path, Url, folderId]);
  }
  if (output.length) {
    var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
  var childFolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) { // Iterate through folders in folder
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var childFolderName = childFolder.getName();
     getChildFiles(
      folderName + ' |--> ' + childFolderName,
      childFolder,
      sheet
    );   
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i get the `childFolderId` and push it into the array together with the `fileID` , `fileName`, and `path`?

Comment: @lamblichus i have uploaded the question on this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870631/how-can-i-pass-a-stored-value-from-one-while-another-while] and i havent get any solution yet. Please have a look