# How can I pass a stored value from one "while" another "while"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheet, I have already list out all the filtered files as needed throughout the parent folder and child folder. I have pushed all the important details into the sheet as well.

My issue now is I am trying to get each **childFolderId** value from *childFolders while* and pass it into the *fileIter while* and then push into a list of array to be displayed in Google Sheet.

Here is the codes:

```
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);                          
                
getChildFiles(parentName, parent, currentSheet, list, excluded);
```

The main function is:

```
function getChildFiles(parentName, parent, sheet) {

var fileIter = parent.searchFiles("title contains 'completed'and title contains 'Verification 
Visit Direct Suppliers'and mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'"); 

var output = [];

var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
  var childFolder = childFolders.next();
  var childFolderName = childFolder.getName();

getChildFiles(
  parentName + ' |--> ' + childFolderName, childFolder,sheet
  );   

 } 

while (fileIter.hasNext()) { 
 var file = fileIter.next();
 var fileName = file.getName();
 var fileID = file.getId();

 var path = parentName + ' |--> ' + fileName;

 output.push([fileID, fileName, path]);
}

 if (output.length) {
 var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
 sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, output.length, 3).setValues(output);
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
} 

}
```

I am trying to get the **childFolderId** without messing up the filtering code. This is because if i insert the ***fileIter while*** inside the ***childFolders while***, None of the files is listed in the google sheet.

But if i split both ***while*** i manage to list all the files i need except the **childFolderId**

How can I get the value of **childFolderId** and push it into the sheet?

Comment: Please let me know if there is any part of the question sounds confusing?

Comment: Try provide a [mcve] with emphasis on the minimal.  Your full code is for you but if you want us to help you then I'd recommend starting from scratch and give us a minimal example that produces the same problem.

Comment: @Cooper I have edited my question is it good to go?

Comment: I really can't figure what you want.  But I'm think that may you need to learn how to use  recursion.

Comment: @Cooper Im actually trying to call the "childfolder id" and trying to push it into array together with the `fileID`, `fileName`, and `path`. This is what i am actually trying to do.